# Quartz scheduler cluster - Job should execute on specific nodes

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am running quartz scheduler in clustered mode comprising of 4 nodes -

- node01a
- node01b
- node02a
- node02b

I need to define 2 schedules - execute a job01 every 10 secs and a job02 every 30 secs.

Job01 should be executed on node01a or node01b

Job02 should be executed on node02a or node02b

Is there a way I can achieve this with quartz scheduler?